# how to find all <p> tags under one tag

Tags: html, dom, tags

I have code like this:

```
<p>Imnsxmn . jwbxhjwvxhvx"><a href="http://aaaaaa.com/" title="View all posts in " rel="category tag">MBA Business School</a> &bull; </div>
<p>wjhdghw</p>
<h4><a href="http://list.com/" rel="bookmark" title="delhi ">code help</a>  </h4>
<p>acavgcsgcsc sv sv</p>
.....
.......
.......
```

So what I want to is that I have to extract all p tags which comes under particular tag. I am curremtly using HTML dom library. Any help ?

Comment: Using what language and/or platform?

Comment: could you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "under" means "inside" and not "after":

Use the [getElementsByTagName method](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html) of the DOM node.

Comment: i think OP is mentioning something like `particular tag > p`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a loop

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
    ... p[i] ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is what you need to do, using html dom library:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();  

$html->load("<p>Imnsxmn . jwbxhjwvxhvx"><a href='http://aaaaaa.com/' title='View all posts in ' rel='category tag'>MBA Business School</a> </div><p>wjhdghw</p><h4><a href='http://list.com/' rel='bookmark' title='delhi '>code help</a></h4><p>acavgcsgcsc sv sv</p>");

# get all p tags that are inside sometag
$collection = $html->find('sometag p');
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use jquery.

`$("#number p")` -> gives all ps' under id=number element.

`$(".my p")` -> gives all ps' under the my class dom element